# How to check the version of the datetime module in python?

Tags: python

I know that this question was asked million of time regarding other libraries. However none of the answers in other discussions was helpful.

I tried:

```
import datetime
print datetime.version

import datetime
print datetime._version_

import datetime
print datetime.__version__
```

None is working.

It says

> attribute error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute '*version*'

Same for the others.

This library do have versions:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime

Comment: The `datetime` you are importing is part of the Python Standard Library. The library you link to is not, it's different. The version is, I suppose, the same as your Python interpreter's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime` is different with `DateTime`. `datetime` is the native Python library, while your link is a third party library. Try using `pkg_resources`

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("DateTime").version
```

Comment: Thanks. i diffident realize there are two packages

Answer (score 4):

As `datetime` is a build-in package, it correspondences with your Python installation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

The [DateTime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime) module you provided is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

The DateTime library on pypi is very old and indicates:

> This package provides a DateTime data type, as known from Zope 2. Unless you need to communicate with Zope 2 APIs, you're probably better off using Python's built-in datetime module.

The library itself gives you no way to interrogate its version.

However setup tools can get you version info from the egg file:

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution 
date_time_version = get_distribution("DateTime").version
```